# Why does Google Analytics not show data for a specific campaign?

Tags: google-analytics, campaigns

The data for a campaign that I run is shown in the Campaign manager report but not in GA (it shows no data available) The tags are well implemented.

Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Which version of GA are you using, the new GA4?

Comment: How is the campaign data injected?  Do you use `utm_` parameters for it, is it done with Adwords auto-tagging, or do you have custom JS code?